# XrController.hitTest not returning any ESTIMATED_SURFACE or DETECTED_SURFACE results

Tags: 8thwall-web

I'm calling

```
XrController.hitTest(X, Y, ['FEATURE_POINT','ESTIMATED_SURFACE', 'DETECTED_SURFACE'])
```

But all the results I'm getting are of type 'FEATURE_POINT' only.

If I leave out 'FEATURE_POINT' from the included types

```
XrController.hitTest(X, Y, ['ESTIMATED_SURFACE', 'DETECTED_SURFACE'])
```

I'm not getting any results at all.

Are 'ESTIMATED_SURFACE', 'DETECTED_SURFACE' not implemented yet, or do I need to do something specific in order to get them

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ESTIMATED_SURFACE` and `DETECTED_SURFACE` options are in the spec but aren't currently a features of 8th Wall Web. Only `FEATURE_POINT` is currently implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only 'FEATURE_POINT' is supported in 8th Wall. You can reference this document: https://www.8thwall.com/docs/web/#xr8xrcontrollerhittest